# UIView - resize to fit contents

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I have created a subclass of UIView that has this property

```
@propert (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *tags;
```

The *tags* array contains a list of strings that the view should display. The view should adjust its size according to the number of tags it displays. Who should be responsible for adjusting the view's size?

1. Should it be the view itself? (in response to property change)
2. Should it be the controller managing the view?
3. Should the controller managing the view ask it for its current size? (after setting the *tags* property)

Answer (score 0):

Superview is responsible for placement of subviews. However in certain scenarios the size of subview can vary than the static size specified by superview. In such cases superview can be relayout. Each subview is then queried for `sizeThatFits:` to return the precise size.
So, override `sizeThatFits:` method in subview and return the dynamic size that is required by the view to precisely fit its content/subviews.

Comment: It didn't work for me, sorry. This may be because the view I was talking about is set as the header view of a UITableView. I've read that to resize it I need to set the tableHeaderView property again.

Comment: In that case you need to return appropriate height for table view header in the tableview method.

Comment: It's not a table view section header, but a header for the whole table view.